# Media meta file system for windows

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-management, tags

I have a large assortment of media that is currently arranged using folders. As the library has grown I've started to notice that folders aren't the best at conveying meaning. Also as the number of folders serving as categories/tags has grown has lead to data duplication for not realizing it was already filed under a different tag.

As I started to think about this I realized tag cloud visualization would be tremendously powerful and figured there has to be something like this out there.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager), [TaggedFrog](http://lunarfrog.com/) seems to be your best bet.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried out TaggedFrog and this seems to be on the right idea other than I found it sucked and it didn't work properly. The autotagging feature in it is exactly the type of thing I'm looking for but it seemed to just ignore more than 5-6 rules when I'd probably have 50-100 if I fully did it out. Which lead it to being uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use hardlinks or symlinks to put a file into multiple folders.  This has its own set of problems, but [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) could help.

Comment: +1 that's an interesting solution, it looks like it would be way too much of a PITA to actually do however. I probably have 5000 things to tag.

Answer (score 1):

Tags already exist as part of Windows 7. See this article :
[Tag your files for easier searches in Windows 7](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/tag-your-files-for-easier-searches-in-windows-7/4024).

You can then use Windows Search with `Tag: filter`. This is further explained in:
[Take advantage of Search filters in Windows Explorer](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/take-advantage-of-search-filters-in-windows-explorer/3915?tag=mantle_skin;content).

If this doesn't suit your needs, you could use the free [tag2find](http://www.tag2find.com/).
Its usage is described in the article 
[Tag2Find Tag Files in Windows for Better Organization](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tag2find-%E2%80%93-tag-your-windows-files-with-web-like-tags/).
Since it supports drag-and-drop onto its window, this could speed-up the tagging process.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft decided to make this feature entirely worthless by not making it work with ALL files. (And I don't think it works on folders)

Comment: Found above a freeware that might do.